# How do you decide which aliased method to call in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

In the Ruby API I notice a lot of methods are aliased.  For instance to iterate over the lines in a `String` I can call `str.lines` or `str.each_line`.

How do you decide which one to use?  Are some alias names deprecated and remain for historic reasons?  Or are aliases just part of the Ruby philosophy of many ways to do the same thing and chosen based on making readable code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Often many methods which do the same thing are provided to allow your code to be more expressive and "sentence like".

`#lines` might make this code read more like a sentence:

```
if paragraph.lines.count < 3
  puts "Your paragraph is small and pathetic."
end
```

While `#each_line` might read better here:

```
report_file.each_line do |line|
  process line
end
```

Answer (score 3):

My advice would be to pick the method's name which makes your code the most self-explanatory.
Besides, there are methods which are more commonly used than others and it also would be a good idea to choose the name which is the quickest understood by other developers.

Answer (score 3):

In most cases it depends on your background as to which fits best. Enumerable is full of aliases for things with `collect` for Ruby people and `map` for those that prefer the Perl style even though they are exactly the same thing.

If you're working on a code base that has already established a preference to one over the other, try to be consistent. If you're working on something new, you're pretty much free to choose, but I'd suggest picking the one that requires the least amount of explanation to another developer.

Sometimes there are two ways to do things. `String#lines` used to return an array of lines in Ruby 1.8.7 but has since been improved to take a block and is given an alias of `String#each_line` to reflect how it is now an iterator.

You'll discover historical artifacts like this from time to time. If you are working on something that must be compatible with Ruby 1.8.7 then you will have to choose the method that works in that environment.

Answer (score 2):

Really, it's programmer's choice unless your organization has specific rules. The aliases are there to provide alternate names that might be more familiar to a developer based on their history of using other languages.